# Keras, simple model, shapes incompatible, but why?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm working on a first model in Keras, just to get started. I downloaded the MNIST data from Kaggle, which has preprocessed a subset of the data into a csv with a label column and 784 (28x28) greyscale pixel values.

I'm getting a ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible. I can't understand why.

Here's my code:

```
## load csv and partition into train/dev sets

dataframe = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv') ##load as pandas
dev_df = dataframe.sample(n=3000, random_state=1)
train_df = dataframe.drop(dev_df.index)
assert train_df.shape[1] == 785    #make sure it's not a problem with the data shape.

##Build the model

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784))
x = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs)
model.summary()
```

At this point, I get the following model summary, which looks right to me (i.e., it looks a lot like what I'm seeing in the guides that I'm following.)

```
Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 784)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
rescaling_6 (Rescaling)      (None, 784)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 100)               78500     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 100)               10100     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 10)                1010      
=================================================================
Total params: 89,610
Trainable params: 89,610

Non-trainable params: 0
```

Then

```
## compile and fit model.

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy")
(X, y) = (train_df.drop('label', axis=1).to_numpy(), train_df['label'].to_numpy())
assert X.shape[1] == 784            ## we're really sure this is the right size.
assert X.shape[0] == y.shape[0]     ## the number of labels matches the number of samples
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=64)
```

The last line raises the error. I would guess it emerges with the final dense layer, since it has the expected (None,10) shape, but I can't figure out where the (None, 1) shaped entity (whatever it is) comes from.

Comment: if u have 1D numerical encoded target u should use sparse_categorical_crossentropy instead of categorical_crossentropy

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks.